# parse json data without key into an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, parsing

```
     NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
            NSInteger success = 1;
            NSLog(@"%d",success);




NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

                NSString *firstResult = jsonArray[0];

                NSLog(firstResult);
```

> (
>           1971,
>           "UPPER BEARING",
>           T4,
>           2,
>           1,
>           "",
>           TU073MB4,
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           554,
>           "",
>           ""
>       ),
>           (
>           1972,
>           "UPPER BEARING",
>           T4,
>           2,
>           2,
>           "",
>           TU073MB4,
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           554,
>           "",
>           ""
>       ),

im quite new to json wihout key. im trying to parse the json data (above) into an array inside xcode.but it keep showing error. any help? thanks

Comment: show the code you're using, include also the error message text

Comment: NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
                
                    NSString *firstResult = jsonArray[0];
                    
                    NSLog(firstResult);

Comment: please edit the question, don't add code in comments (it's really hard to read) - you can also format nicely in the question

Comment: it said incompatible types sending 'NSdictionary' to parameter of type  'NSdata'* _nonNnull

Comment: so you already have the decoded JSON and you don't need to use `NSJSONSerialization`. or you have the types set incorrectly somewhere when you wrote the code

Comment: if i already have the decoded JSON, how do i put it into array?

Comment: you need to show more code. it looks like you have an array of arrays from your JSON snippet, but none of the information you've given is complete enough for us to know

Comment: i only made that line. i already catch the data into the log. but i did not manage to put it into the array.

Comment: `jsonData` came from somewhere - where? provide the full response for `NSLog(@"%@", jsonData);`

Comment: there. i edited the code. the 'NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);' show the data. but i didnt manage to put into array

Comment: so why would you use `SBJsonParser` and then use `NSJSONSerialization`? you seem to be confused about what you're getting and how to deserialise and then use it - you only need to deserialise it once, then you have access to the contents and you can index into the unpacked data

Comment: now i get it... so now i just have to put the jsonData into the array right? because the data is on the jsonData. am i right?

Comment: i'd expecting that `jsonData` is a dictionary or an array of arrays, i'm not 100% sure. you can take whatever you want out of it, but it does have the unpacked data in it already, you don't need to copy / move it somewhere else

Comment: it says "`expected method to read array element not found on object of type "NSDictionary`""

heres what i add `NSLog(@"%@", jsonData[0]);`

Comment: what did i do wrong here?

Comment: you are telling the compiler you have a dictionary and then trying to use it as an array